# How can I add more parameters in Android Firebase database post?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently using the Firebase github [example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/NewPostActivity.java) to create an app where users register and can post "status updates." I am able to do that correctly, but now I would like to add more parameters, like user location (latitude and longitude), but I am not sure where I would place this at. I am not sure at what point everything that is going to be added is added. Here is my current code:

NewPostActivity:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

private EditText mTextField;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_post);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postText);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabSubmitPost);
    assert fab != null;
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submitPost();
        }
    });
}

private void submitPost() {
    final String text = mTextField.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        mTextField.setError("Required");
        return;
    }

    final String userId = getUid();
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            if (user == null) {
                Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Could not fetch user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                writeNewPost(userId, user.username, text);
            }
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String text) {
    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, text);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

and this is the post file:

```
public class Post {

    public String uid;
    public String author;
    public String text;
    public int likeCount = 0;
    public Map<String, Boolean> likes = new HashMap<>();

    public Post() {

    }

    public Post(String uid, String author, String text) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.author = author;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("uid", uid);
        result.put("author", author);
        result.put("text", text);
        result.put("likeCount", likeCount);
        result.put("likes", likes);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: where you want to have `latitude and longitude` ? with the **post** along with other parameters ?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi yes, I believe that would be best? You don't think?

Comment: Sure it is but lately depends on your use case :) posting an answer for that see if that helps

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi Well I want to post a new post with location. If I am near that location again, I want to be able to see it, if not, I don't want to see it. Great, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add `Latitude & Longitude` when you save a `Post` you can add both the parameters to your existing class, you will need to modify `Post` class constructor to add 2 more arguments like :

```
public double lat,lng;

public Post(String uid, String author, String text,double lat,double lng) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.author = author;
    this.text = text;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
}
```

then in your `toMap` function you can add the parameters to `result` like :

```
result.put("lat", lat);
result.put("lng", lng);
```

So when you call the constructor in your `writeNewPost` function you can change this line :

```
Post post = new Post(userId, username, text);
```

to

```
Post post = new Post(userId, username, text, lat, lng);
```

now your new post will be posted alongwith with latitude and longitude

i am assuming that you already have the **latitude and longitude** with you

**Update**

As you want to see the `Posts` that are posted within a `Location` you have posted them, you can do something like this,

In the `Firebase query` where you are querying the `posts` you can add `orderByChild` and `equalTo`filter to compare with current `latitude & Longitude`,

and if you want filter them based on some distance then you will have to query all the `posts` and then compare them locally